# Transform recursive xml into Json with php

Tags: php, json, xml

I'm trying to transform XML into Json via PHP and I don't know how to serialize objects. Basically, I have in input an XML file (file.xml) with a recursive structure and I would like to transpose it into Json (out.json).

xml file sample:

```xml
<Transfer>
 <Name>Transfer</Name>
 <Title>Transfer + Date</Title>
 <Level1>
   <Name>Item 1</Name>
   <Title>Title 1</Title>
   <className>middle-level</className>
   <Level2>
      <Name>Item 1.1</Name>
      <Title>Title 1.1</Title>
      <className>product-dept</className>
   </Level2>
   <Level2>
      <Name>Item 1.2</Name>
      <Title>Title 1.2</Title>
      <className>product-dept</className>
      <Level3>
          <Name>Item 1.2.1</Name>       
          <Title>Title 1.2.1</Title>            
          <className>pipeline1</className>        
      </Level3>        
      <Level3>            
          <Name>Item 1.2.2</Name>            
          <Title>Title 1.2.2</Title>            
          <className>pipeline1</className>        
      </Level3>
    </Level2>  
  </Level1>  
  <Level1>    
    <Name>Item 2</Name>    
    <Title>Title 2</Title>    
    <className>middle-level</className>  
  </Level1>
</Transfer>
```

Json output desired :

```json
{
    'name': 'Transfer',
    'title': 'transfer Date',
    'children': [
      { 'name': 'Item 1', 'title': 'Title 1', 'className': 'middle-level',
        'children': [
          { 'name': 'Item 1.1', 'title': 'Title 1.1', 'className': 'product-dept' },
          { 'name': 'Item 1.2', 'title': 'Title 1.2', 'className': 'product-dept',
            'children': [
              { 'name': 'Item 1.2.1', 'title': 'Title 1.2.1', 'className': 'pipeline1' },
              { 'name': 'Item 1.2.2', 'title': 'Title 1.2.2', 'className': 'pipeline1' },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { 'name': 'Item 2', 'title': 'Title 2', 'className': 'middle-level'}
    ]
  }
```

All this with php code :

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
$result = [];

foreach ($xml->Level1 as $value) 
{
    
    $child = [];
    $child['Name'] = (string)$value->Name;
    $child['Title'] = (string)$value->Title;
    $child['className'] = (string)$value->className;


    foreach ($xml->Level2 as $level2)
    {
        $child = [];
        $child['Level2'] = (string)$value->Level2->Name;
    }

    $result[] = $child;
    
}

$json_string = json_encode($result);
print_r($json_string);
```

Currently, I'm just transforming a part of the graph but I don't understand how to do more.
I think that what I want to do is not too complex but I am blocked.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $result = [];
    $result['name'] = (string)$xml->Name;
    $result['title'] = (string)$xml->Title;

    foreach ($xml->Level1 as $value)
    {

        $child = [];
        $item = [];
        $item['name'] = (string)$value->Name;
        $item['title'] = (string)$value->Title;
        $item['className'] = (string)$value->className;

        foreach ($value->Level2 as $level2)
        {
            $child2 = [];
            foreach ($level2->Level3 as $level3) {
                $child2[] = array(
                    'name' => (string)$level3->Name,
                    'title' => (string)$level3->Title,
                    'className' => (string)$level3->className,
                );
            }
            $child[] = array(
                'name' => (string)$level2->Name,
                'title' => (string)$level2->Title,
                'className' => (string)$level2->className,
                'children' => $child2,
            );
        }

        $item['children'] = $child;
        $result['children'][] = $item;
    }
    $json_string = json_encode($result);
    print_r($json_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with a structure of unkown depth, the  stack is usually your best friend:

```php
function xmlToJson($node, $level = 1)
{
    $children = [];
    if (isset($node->${'Level' . $level})) {
        foreach ($node->${'Level' . $level} as $value) {
            $children[] = [
                'name' => (string)$value->Name,
                'title' => (string)$value->Title,
                'className' => (string)$value->className,
                'children' => xmlToJson($value, $level + 1),
            ];
        }
    }

    return $children;
}
```

This code will start at level one and fetch all the names, titles and classNames. Then it calls itself, creating a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). Because of this, you need to make sure that level exists, hence the `if (isset(...))` before actually accessing the level.

The function will terminate if it stops calling itself, which is when there are no more levels to descent down to.